# MAUI make button resize to fit text

Tags: xaml, maui

How can i make a button resize itself to fit the entire text. Currently i have a `CollectionView` that gets populated with buttons with text from a collection. The issue i have is that the button does not expand to fit the text and for all buttons generated, the width is identical. Is it possible to make each button size itself just to fit in the text within it?

```
<CollectionView x:Name="TagsView"
                    Grid.Row="0">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Text="{Binding Name}"
                        CornerRadius="15" 
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

What it looks like at the moment:

[image: What it looks like at the moment]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to make a button resize itself to fit the entire text, you need to set propeties `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` of this button like below:

```
 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
```

And then,you should add a `LinearItemsLayout` with `Horizontal` **Orientation** like below:

```
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

Comment: Worked beautifully, thanks

Comment: HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions are not used to "resize itself to fit the entire text".
They are used for alignment, and to make the control take extra space, if such space is available. Then again, if such place is available, the button will expand to fit its text, by its default behavior.